# What data can be derived from ECDSA signature and message?

Tags: dsa, secp256k1

I generate a random message `m` sent to a device that calculates `sig(m, privKey)` with `secp256k1`. It then performs an HTTP GET call to share both `pubKey` and `sig` with the [purpose of authentication](https://github.com/fiatjaf/lnurl-rfc/blob/luds/04.md).

(`m` remains private to me and is randomly generated for every new authentication request. **EDIT**: it crypto terms it might be called a "challenge"?)

I want to derive a constant secret from `m` and `sig`, `m'` and `sig'`, `m''` and `sig''` and so on.

My first thought was to use ECDSA public key recovery, that would deterministically yield the same data (the public key) each time. This would work, but there are issues:

- ECDSA public key recovery might return 0, 1 or 2 possible EC points (public keys), as far as I understand.
- The device made an HTTP call with the public key in the URL (even over SSL it might be prone to attacks).

If public key recovery returned 2 public keys, the one not shared by the device would be perfect. But how often does one get 2 public keys?

Are there alternative methods, with any cryptographic tools, to reliably derive a secret for any given `m` and `sig`? Thank you!

Comment: Apologies in advance if I misused some terms, I'm a crypto n00b

Comment: A public key should be considered public, and for it to be useful for authentication, it also needs to be trusted. Sharing both a public key and signature created with that key makes no sense whatsoever. A signature is also considered public, so if you can derive a public key from that you cannot use it as secret. Maybe it would be better if you would describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to use [lnurl-auth](https://github.com/fiatjaf/lnurl-rfc/blob/luds/04.md) which uses the bitcoin private key to derive and sign challenges that are used as proof when signing into websites. I want to use it but locally in order to automatically calculate my passwords. Essentially as a password manager. And if it works then share it with others.

Comment: Since message (which is private) along with the signature (which is public) is required for finding the unused, unpublished public key I thought it made sense.

Comment: You cannot verify a signature if you don't know the message $m$. Verification requires the public key, message, and the signature itself.

Comment: @meshcollider Let me clarify: The message `m` is private to me, I know it, I generated it randomly. The device reads it (via QR code) and outputs public key and signature. Then I have the three pieces to verify the signature, so now I know the device (user) is who he says he is. Would that help with my original question?

Comment: Maybe my use of the word "message" is confusing? In the spec they use "challenge" so perhaps that makes it more clear.

Comment: Might I suggest it might be cleaner to start by describing the problem, rather than your solution.  What are you trying to achieve?  What are your resources?  What security goals do you have?